# Jasmine: test a setTimeout function throws an error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, settimeout, jasmine

I would like to test the error handling of a method, which schedules work with setTimeout. The error will be thrown in the scheduled part, i.e.:

```
function sutWithSetTimeout() {
    setTimeout(function () { throw new Error("pang"); }, 1);
}
```

How do I test that an error is thrown and that it has the correct message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to catch the function in the `setTimeout` and call them using `expect(function(){fn();}).toThrow(e);`. So you can spy on `setTimeout` to get the function:

```
spyOn(window, 'setTimeout');
sutWithSetTimeout();
var fn = window.setTimeout.mostRecentCall.args[0];
expect(fn).toThrow('pang');
```