# Can Jasmine be made to test for concurrency failures?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, settimeout

I suspect based on other responses (like [Jasmine: test a setTimeout function throws an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176499/jasmine-test-a-settimeout-function-throws-an-error) and [How to test a function which has a setTimeout with jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955201/how-to-test-a-function-which-has-a-settimeout-with-jasmine/10955536#10955536)) that there's no good solution here, but I want to figure out how to better deal with the second test below:

```
describe('Tests', function () {
    it('succeed', function () { expect(true).toBeTruthy(); });
    it('have problems', function(done) {
        setTimeout(function() { console.log(undefined.foo); });
        setTimeout(done, 5);
    });

    it('fail', function() { fail; });
    it('also fail', function() { fail; });
});
```

Jasmine's current behavior here is to run the first test and then bail out when the rogue exception-causing setTimeout is encountered in the second test; the last two failing specs never run.

My use case doesn't look like this, of course! The asynchronous error is happening somewhere down a call stack, over a river, and through the woods. And it's obviously an error that it happens and isn't caught! But it's unfortunate if such errors will always terminate Jasmine itself, rather than causing a test case failure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `try...catch` or promises alongside Jasmine's `done.fail()`.

**Promises:**

```
it('gets some huge file', done => {
  getFile('http://movies.com/holymountain.mp4')
    .then(res => {
      expect(res.status).toBe(200)
      done()
    })
    .catch(done.fail)
})
```

**Try/catch**

```
it('gets some huge file', done => {
  try {
    getFile('http://movies.com/holymountain.mp4')
    expect(getFile.status).toBe(200)
    done()
  } catch (e) {
    // console.log(e) // ???
    done.fail()
  }
})
```

[Issue for reference](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine.github.io/issues/26)